# Getting an object from event handler in the View to an event handler in the ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, events, mvvm

Heres my code in the View.xaml.cs where the object gets created

View

```
void pmi_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MenuItem mi = sender as MenuItem;

    int projectKey = 0;
    projectKey = (int)mi.Tag;
    Project_VM project;
    foreach (var p in GlobalVars._instance.ProjectList)
    {
        if (projectKey == p.ClarityId)
        {
            project = new Project_VM(p.Model);
            Main winMain = Window.GetWindow(this.VisualParent) as Main;

            winMain.Projects.SelectedItem = project;
            winMain.Projects.ScrollIntoView(project);
        }

    }

}
```

I need to figure out a way to get that object to a event handler in the ViewModel which is subscribed to an event using a delegate.

ViewModel

```
void _selectedProject_ChangerSelectedProj(object o, SelectionProjEventArgs e)
{

    foreach (var p in _globalVars.ProjectList)
    {
        if (p.ClarityId.Equals(e.projectKey))
            changeSelectedProject(p);
    }
}
```

So instead of looping through the ProjectList I would like to pass the project object created in the View.xaml.cs. Im updating and refactoring a old WPF application and im pretty new to it. Any suggestions how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

The ViewModel is on the datacontext, simply cast the VM off of it and add the object to it.

```
var myVM = DataContext as MyViewModel ;

if (myVM != null)
  myVM.TargetEventHandler ....
```

Answer (score 0):

I would feel as though it would be better to take this out of your code behind and put it into a function in your view model that is fired on your object click.  I'm not sure what `pmi` is in referenct to the function declariation `pmi_click...`, but if it is a button, the command property can be bound to a public RelayCommand property located in the view model.  Inside your view model constructor, you set your RelayCommand property to be that of a function.  The contents of this function can then complete the same actions as that found within your click function in your code behind.  You would then have access to all the objects inside your view model.